# How to write a function that reads and returns a line from a file descriptor without the '\n' in C

Tags: c

I am only allowed to use malloc, read and free.
I'm also able to use functions from string.h

The program should be compiled using:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -D BUFFER_SIZE=32 get_next_line.c
```

The includes are:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 32
```

The function should be prototyped as :

```
int get_next_line(int fd, char **line);
```

Comment: you read up to **and including** the newline, but do not 'return' the newline

Comment: I imagine you have to do some sort of buffered reading because of that BUFFER_SIZE define, so read a BUFFER_SIZE chunk. Scan it copying its contents to a return array. If a newline is found, reset the position indicator back to one past the newline on the file descriptor and return the array without copying the newline. If a newline was not found, read another chunk and do the same, until a chunk with a newline is found, or EOF is reached. Since this is clearly homework and you haven't shown any attempt of yours, I won't post a complete solution.

Comment: According to your `get_next_line` function prototype, the function returns `int`. What value is it supposed to return? The length of the line read? The second function parameter looks like an array of strings. Are you supposed to store the line read from the file in that array?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I would do something like:

```
  #include <string.h>       // strlen()
  #include <unistd.h>       // read(), write(), close()
  #include <stdlib.h>       // EXIT_SUCCESS, realloc(), free()
  #include <fcntl.h>        // O_RDONLY

  #define EOF (-1)          // Flag to indicate that the end-of-file was encountered.
  extern int errno;         // Used to detect, and report, error information.

  /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ** Read a line from specified file (fd), and return the line in allocated
  ** memory.  The caller is responsible for freeing the returned memory.
  **
  ** Return codes:
  ** -------------
  ** -1 EOF           Encountered the end of the file (fd).
  **  0 EXIT_SUCCESS  Success.
  ** >1 (errno value) Failure.
  */
  int get_next_line(int fd, char **line)
    {
    int    rCode      = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    size_t lineOffset = 0;

    while(!rCode)
      {
      char *newBuf = NULL;
      int   bytes;
      char  ch;

      bytes=read(fd, &ch, sizeof(ch));         // Read one byte from file (fd).
      switch(bytes)
        {
        case (-1):                             // Check for read() error condition.
          rCode=errno;                           // Return errno to caller.
          break;                                 // Return from the function.

        case 0:                                // Check for end-of-file condition.
          rCode = EOF;                           // Return EOF flag to caller.
          ch = '\0';                             // Pretend to have read '\0'.
                                                 // No break.  Fall through to default case.
        default:                               // read() was successful.
          newBuf=realloc(*line, lineOffset+2);   // Modify line's memory allocation as needed.
          if(!newBuf)                            // Check for realloc() error condition.
            {
            rCode=errno;                           // Return errno to caller.
            break;                                 // Return from the function.
            }

          *line = newBuf;                        // realloc() was successful.  Reset line pointer.
          if('\n' == ch)                         // If newline was read, throw it away
            {
            (*line)[lineOffset] = '\0';            // Instead of a newline, terminate the line,
            break;                                 // and return from the function.
            }

          (*line)[lineOffset++] = ch;            // Append the character read from the file to the allocated memory.
          (*line)[lineOffset] = '\0';            // Terminate the string in allocated memory.
          continue;                              // Go back to the top of the while() loop, and read another byte.
        }

      break;
      }

    return(rCode);
    }

  /*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ** Program start.
  */
  int main(int argC, char *argV[])
    {
    int rCode=EXIT_SUCCESS;
    int fd = (-1);
    char *line_A = NULL;

    if(2 != argC)
      {
      char *msg = "Missing filename, or too many command-line arguments.\n";

      write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

    errno=EXIT_SUCCESS;
    fd=open(argV[1], O_RDONLY);
    if((-1) == fd)
      {
      char *msg = "open() failed.\n";

      write(2, msg, strlen(msg));
      goto CLEANUP;
      }

    while(EOF != rCode)
      {
      rCode=get_next_line(fd, &line_A);
      if(rCode > 0)
        goto CLEANUP;

      write(1, line_A, strlen(line_A));
      write(1, "\n", 2);
      }

  CLEANUP:

    if(line_A)
      free(line_A);

    if((-1) != fd)
      close(fd);

    return(rCode);
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm not allowed to use switch, but you're code is incredibly interesting and gave some sort of guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function, that I ended up writing to solve the question

https://github.com/ayoubabounakif/42cursus-GNL/tree/master/get_next_line